# Implementing local cache in-App Purchase in ionic2

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am new to ionic and new to in app purchase. I have a simple use case. I need to know what all in-app products the user has bought from the app. I know from google docs that it provides local cache to store this information.  This is done to avoid a network call.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html

I need to access this in my ionic2 code to determine the behaviour of my app. How can I do that?

I am using : I am using cordova-plugin-inapppurchase 1.1.0 plugin

Answer (score 0):

Which plugin or library you used for implementing in app purchase in your app?